# Audio does not work in upstart job

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, upstart

I'm trying to run the [gmediarender](https://github.com/hzeller/gmrender-resurrect/blob/master/INSTALL.md) UPnP media renderer as an upstart job. When I run it from the command line as myself, everything works fine. When it runs as an upstart job, I get error messages in `/var/log/upstart/gmediarender` and no sound. The error messages are different depending on which audiosink option I use. If I use the `--gstout-audiosink=pulsesink` option the error messages look like:

```
Assertion 'm' failed at pulse/thread-mainloop.c:166, function pa_threaded_mainloop_lock(). Aborting.
```

Without this option the messages look like:

```
AL lib: alsa_open_playback: Could not open playback device 'default': Connection refused
ERROR [2014-03-23 20:57:12.621940 | gstreamer] playsink2: Error: The autoaudiosink element is not working. (Debug: gstplaysink.c(1906): gen_audio_chain (): /GstPlayBin2:play/GstPlaySink:playsink2)
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Regardless of the sink I use and whether it is an upstart job or not, I get these messages:

```
(gmediarender:1146): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_pad_new_from_template: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD_TEMPLATE (templ)' failed

(gmediarender:1146): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_pad_template_get_caps: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD_TEMPLATE (templ)' failed

(gmediarender:1146): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_pad_set_caps: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD (pad)' failed

(gmediarender:1146): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_add_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD (pad)' failed
```

I'm guessing my pulseaudio set up could be better but I wonder what upstart is doing differently from the command line. Seeing as it works from the command line, I don't see why it can't work from upstart. I've tried using the `setuid` and `setgid` stanzas in the upstart configuration:

```
# gmediarender - gmediarender job file

description "UPnP renderer"
author "John Reid <john...reid@netscape.net>"

# Stanzas
#
# Stanzas control when and how a process is started and stopped
# See a list of stanzas here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#respawn

# When to start the service
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

# Expect gmediarender to run as a daemon
#expect daemon

# Run as john
setuid john
setgid pulse

# Start after pulseaudio
#start on started pulseaudio RESULT=ok

# Start the process
exec /usr/local/bin/gmediarender -f HTPC -u 099519151638c684ee01135a43d427ea
#exec /usr/local/bin/gmediarender -f HTPC -u 099519151638c684ee01135a43d427ea --gstout-audiosink=pulsesink
```

`lsb_release -a` gives:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

The box is a mythbuntu set up. I get these messages in `syslog`:

```
Mar 23 20:57:12 htpc pulseaudio[4224]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
Mar 23 20:57:12 htpc pulseaudio[4224]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Mar 23 20:57:12 htpc pulseaudio[4221]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Mar 23 21:03:38 htpc pulseaudio[4430]: [pulseaudio] socket-server.c: bind(): Address already in use
Mar 23 21:03:38 htpc pulseaudio[4430]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-esound-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Update: I tried this on another 13.10 machine and it failed in a similar way. However when running as an upstart session job it worked just fine. I guess I need to work out how to start a user init on my mythbuntu box.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't access a pulseaudio sink from an upstart job is because pulseaudio is not yet running. Per default pulseaudio is (and should be) started from a user session. Therefore you have no issues from running after login.

To overcome this we should therefore run applications relying on a running pulseaudio server in a session **after the user login**.

Alternatively we may try with running pulseaudio in [system wide mode](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/), but as this may lead to unwanted side effects it is not recommended to do so:

- [What is wrong with system mode?](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/) <sup>PulseAudio</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I don't think it is the answer though. AFAICT mythbuntu sets up pulseaudio in system wide mode which I know is not the best. But that said, the upstart job does not work whether it is started at boot or later on when system-wide pulseaudio is already running. I'd like to change pulseaudio to the recommended configuration but I run my TV off this mythbuntu box and it took me some time to get the audio right last time. I don't really want to go through that again.

Comment: Upstart runs as `root` but pulseaudio runs as the logged in `user`. I am not so sure how Mythbuntu does it but fact is, that your upsart job can't access the pulseaudio server, probably because of this. Can't you run gmediarender as a startup app from the user session?

Comment: Maybe I could run it as a startup app, I shall look into that. The setuid and setgid stanzas in the upstart configuration do make my gmediarender job run as the `user` so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Ah yeah - you're right... missed that, sorry. Why did you comment out `start on started pulseaudio RESULT=ok`? Maybe we should wait until pulseaudio was started.

Comment: It didn't seem to make any difference to the outcome so I tried both but pulse is definitely running when I manually upstart `gmediarender`